# I'm sending a month type string from JSP to servlet, then to dao from servlet. How can I get the Year and month from this string?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, java-time, date

How am I supposed to convert the string to Year-MMMM format in mysql, or do I have to convert it in controller portion? 
Suppose: 2019-02 is getting saved as 2019-02, but I want another column that will convert 2019-02 to 2019-February.

JSP portion

```
<form action="YearMonthController" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="CREATE_YearMonth" />

    Month with year: <input type="month" name="year_month">

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

This is the controller portion

```
private void create_a_yearMonth_controller(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    String _yearMonth = request.getParameter("year_month");

    YM ym = new YM(_yearMonth);

    _ymDAO.create_a_yearMonth_dao(ym);

}
```

This is the DAO portion

```
public void create_a_yearMonth_dao(YM ym) throws Exception {

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement prepared_statement = null;

    try {
        connection = data_source.getConnection();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO `years_months`\r\n" + "(yearMonth) \r\n" + "VALUES \r\n" + "(?);";

        prepared_statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        prepared_statement.setString(1, ym.get_yearMonth());

        prepared_statement.execute();
    } finally {
        close(connection, prepared_statement, null);
    }

}
```

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `years_months` (
yearMonth VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (yearMonth)
);
```

Comment: I would advice you to store the year-month as a Date, perhaps with day always set to 1, then you can format the date in either sql or java using standard format functions. Also it will be much easier to use the column in queries where you want to o compare to a date.

Comment: I'm getting the following error if I use date.

HTTP Status 500 - com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '2019-02' for column 'yearMonth' at row 1

Comment: Of course you will need to give a day as well as I mentioned in my previous comment, just set it to 1

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit? Would b e a great help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, just add '-01' to the string before storing it. Mysql should be able to convert a string on the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' to Date automatically

Comment: Maybe you should do some research on basic string handling in java.

Comment: This worked for me.
`String sql = "INSERT INTO `years_months`\r\n" + "(yearMonth) \r\n" + "VALUES \r\n" + "(CONCAT(?,'-01'));";`

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL hasn’t got a year-month datatype (at least I think not), I would store the year and month as `2019-02` alone always (so a `varchar(50)` column is pretty wide for the purpose, `char(7)` would do). This is ISO 8601 format and widely recognized.

In Java I would use a `YearMonth` for the year and month (no need to invent your own class). And format it according to the needs for presentation. `YearMonth.toString` produces the ISO 8601 format mentioned, and `YearMonth.parse` parses it back, so everything fits well together.

```
public void createAYearMonthDao(YearMonth ym) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO `years_months` (yearMonth) VALUES (?);";

    try (Connection connection = data_source.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, ym.toString());
        preparedStatement.execute();
    }
}
```

To produce a string like `2019-February` whenever you need that:

```
    DateTimeFormatter ymFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);

    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY);
    String formattedYm = ym.format(ymFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedYm);
```

Output:

> 2019-February

`YearMonth` has methods for getting the year and month separately, for example:

```
    System.out.println("Year " + ym.getYear() + " month " + ym.getMonth());
```

> Year 2019 month FEBRUARY

The alternative suggestion in the comments to use `date` in MySQL and `LocalDate` in Java isn’t bad either. Pro: You save formatting and parsing on saving and retrieval. Con: You got a redundant day of month in your database.